# Azure AppService Autoscale feature

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, scaleout

I enabled the scaleout setting for my Azure App Service.

[image]

However, when I go to the Autoscale setting, choose the App Service Plan, and see that the autocale is not enabled.

[image]

Please help me to explain what is the difference between these features, or what wrong with my configuration?

Comment: This is because you have selected Automatic Scaling which will only autoscale the web app depending on the load without the need to set up any rule, When you select Rule based autoscale feature like here-1) https://i.imgur.com/27BjsNv.png  2) https://i.imgur.com/A3LA6fh.png 3) https://i.imgur.com/2JX01MW.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to see the **`Rule`** in the **`Custom autoscale`** because you have used [**`Automatic Preview`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-automatic-scaling?tabs=azure-portal#enable-automatic-scaling) ***Autoscale option which does not require you to manage the rule manually as it will be handled by your Web App automatically depending on the Load.***

[image]

You can check if the Web app is autoscaled by checking the Instance count in the App Service Plan option in Overview tab:-
Here- ***P1 indicates the Premium plan and 1 count indicates the instances that are scaled or used by the Web app***:-

[image]

As you are using Premium tier the Memory and CPU size is already more, Thus the Website will autoscale automatically only when the desired threshold is met.

You can create the ***Auto-scale rule manually*** by selecting **`Rule Based option`** like below:-

I created one sample Rule for Standard Tier app just for demonstration:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, When the traffic in my Web app increased, The **`autoscale`** ran successfully and the ***`Instances were added according to my rule above`***:-

[image]

[image]